# Why does css line-height * rows not always equal height?

Tags: css

For example like this:

[image: example]

> In this example, the line-height is **18.858px** and there are **8** rows, so I would expect a height of **150.864**, but instead the height is only **144px**.

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sammet-rhgrx?file=/src/App.tsx

> In this example
>
> In Chrome: `line-height = font-size * line-height`, but `height = Math.floor(line-height) * row`
>
> In FireFox: `line-height = font-size * line-height`
>
> In Safari: `line-height = Math.floor(font-size * line-height)`

Comment: Is your browser changing the text size? Or zoom level?  Do you have padding or margins on things?  Is that a single block element?

Comment: No, You can view this CodeSandBox link https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-sammet-rhgrx?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Take your example on codesandbox.io, apply the style `* {margin:0;padding:0}` and then the height of App, and the sum of all the heights of it's children are both 158px. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-mahavira-csigs

Comment: View the CodeSandBox console in Chrome,   when `line-height: 1.1`,  getComputedStyle result is `height: 13px lineHeight 13.2px`

Comment: the link you added in the question demonstrate nothing since you are editing it. Consider adding an example inside your question